# If Query Post Returns 1 Post

Tags: query-posts

I have been using Query Post for a newsticker which I have created so that the user navigate through the number of news by simply pressing Next & Previous buttons.
But in case if there is only 1 news (i.e, only 1 post returned then there is no point of having Prev and Next button).

I will simply assign css attribute Display: none to the prev and next button if there is only 1 post. But how to find out if the query post returned just 1 post.

```
query_posts('post_type=post&cat=20&post_status=publish&order=DESC');     
while (have_posts()): the_post();
```

Comment: I **strongly** recommend you look at: http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-netherlands-2012

Answer (score 1):

You should not use [query_post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) when you can use the mutch faster query [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

You can count the post with the property [post_count](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties).

Here is a snippet that counts your post in the loop:

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type'     =>  'post',
    'cat'           =>  '20',
    'post_status'   =>  'publish',
    'order'         =>  'DESC'

    );

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

    if( ( $the_query->post_count <= 1 ) {
        echo 'One or less';

    } else {

        echo 'More than one post';
    }

endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Comment: Something [to read](http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-netherlands-2012).